# Not able to increse count if .likecount div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch int value between div and on user like it should increse the count.
but I am not handling when there is no data between div.

my html code

```
<div class="thumbnail" id="123">
    <ul>
        <li class="likeStatus"><a href="#" id="likeitlink" title="like this">Like</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="likecount">
            </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#likeitlink', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    var msgid = $(this).parents('.thumbnail').attr('id');
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likeStatus').html('<a href="#" id="Unlikeitlink" title="Unlike this">Unlike</a>');
    if ($.trim($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount')).is(':empty')) {
        $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0");
         alert($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0"));
    }

    $likesNo = parseInt($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html(), 10);
    alert($likeNo);
    $likesNo++;
    // alert($likeNo);
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("" + $likesNo);
});
```

I tried code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/hLetjwg8/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you had problem reading "likecount" value so Below is the solution just replace if condition

```
 if (!$.trim($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html())) {
            $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0");
            alert($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html());
  }
```

Comment: like count is not increasing??

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to teach you how to fish. I am not however going to give you a fish.

Follow these instructions in Google Chrome:

1. Right click the browser window
2. Click "Inspect Element"
3. Click your like link so that it fires the onclick trigger.
4. Click the "Console" tab and there you'll see an error
5. Click the (index):26 link on the right hand side in the console. You'll see your exact problem.

Comment: I resolved error ` if ($.trim($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount')).is(':empty')) {` now on click it is showing `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: yes that was also the problem thats why i have told u to replace that with other

Answer (score 0):

First Step Remove whitespaces in the link

```
<a href="#" class="likecount"></a>
```

Replace

```
 if ($.trim($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount')).is(':empty')) {
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0");
     alert($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0"));
}
```

with

```
if (($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount')).html() == '') {
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0");
     alert($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0"));
}
```

so your new code becomes

```
$(document).on('click', '#likeitlink', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    var msgid = $(this).parents('.thumbnail').attr('id');
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likeStatus').html('<a href="#" id="Unlikeitlink" title="Unlike this">Unlike</a>');
    if (($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount')).html() == '') {
        $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0");
         alert($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0"));
    }

    $likesNo = parseInt($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html(), 10);
    alert($likesNo);
    $likesNo++;
    alert($likesNo);
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("" + $likesNo);
});
```

and html code

```
<div class="thumbnail" id="123">
<ul>
    <li class="likeStatus">
        <a href="#" id="likeitlink" title="like this">Like</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="likecount"></a> 
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

if u want to do it with whitespace

```
$(document).on('click', '#likeitlink', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    var msgid = $(this).parents('.thumbnail').attr('id');
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likeStatus').html('<a href="#" id="Unlikeitlink" title="Unlike this">Unlike</a>');
    var prev = $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html();
    prev = parseInt(prev) || 0;
    if (prev == 0) {
        $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("0");
    }

    $likesNo = parseInt($('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html(), 10);
    $likesNo++;
    $('#' + msgid + ' .likecount').html("" + $likesNo);
});
```

Comment: there is a space in `<a href="#" class="likecount">   </a>` how to resolve this

Comment: remove that space in your code because if there will be any space then it will not be null

Comment: if u want to make it work with whitespace u can do this

Comment: dont remove space just change the javascript code with the last code block of my answer